# Locking by value

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a multi-threaded Java application appending to a variety of files at dynamically generated paths (large numbers -- over 100k). I want to protect against concurrent writes. Because this is contention within the JVM, I can't use the `FileLock`s.

Instead, I've been trying to synchronize on `Path` objects as follows (`PathLocker` is a singleton).

```
 public class PathLocker {
    private final ConcurrentMap<Path, ReentrantLock> pathLockMap = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

    public void lock(Path path) {
        pathLockMap.computeIfAbsent(path, p -> new ReentrantLock()).lock();
    }

    public void unlock(Path path) {
        ReentrantLock reentrantLock = pathLockMap.get(path);
        if (!reentrantLock.hasQueuedThreads()) { // NPE OCCURS HERE
            pathLockMap.remove(path);
        }
        reentrantLock.unlock();
    }
}
```

The only client code looks like this:

```
Path path = findPath(directory, dataType, bucketEnd, referenceId);
pathLocker.lock(path);
try {
    try (FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(path.toFile(), true)) {
        fileWriter.write(string);
    }
} finally {
    pathLocker.unlock(path);
}
```

However, this code fairly quickly throws a null pointer when it dereferences `reentrantLock` within `PathLocker::unlock`.

I do not understand how this NPE can occur. Clearly, some other thread has removed the value in the meanwhile, but -- as I understand it -- the only possible threads that could remove the lock would be those that were queued and waiting for the lock in the first place. What am I missing?

Comment: At which line in PathLocker is NPE?

Comment: @mst: added a comment in the code showing where.

Comment: Note that you cannot safely lock on arbitrary `Path` objects because it's possible for different `Path` objects to point to the same physical location.  An [`Interner`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Interner.html) strategy can work around this, but generally speaking you can't reliably lock on concepts outside the JVM with Java locks.  You need an external mechanism (e.g. if two instances of your program ran at the same time).

Comment: @dimo414 note I'm not locking on `Path` objects.

Comment: "*I've been trying to synchronize on `Path` objects*" - synchronization is a form of locking. Unless I'm miss-parsing that statement, locking on `Path`'s is exactly what you're doing.

Comment: @dimo414, what you're saying only has bearing with the `synchronized` keyword. If you look at the code, you'll see I'm not using that keyword at all, much less on a `Path`.

Comment: Fair enough, but the general problem isn't necessarily limited to `synchronized`.  Any usage of `Path` as a lock object risks misses, because effectively-equal `Path`s can still be non-equal according to `.equals()`.  E.g. `Paths.get(".").equals(Paths.get("./."))` will return `false`.  If your `findPath()` method always returns `Path`'s in the same format that *may* not be an issue, but it'd be easy to muddle up.  Personally I would never use `Path`s as `Map` keys.

Answer (score 2):

There is small posibilty that between `computeIfAbsent` and `lock` function in thread 1 was invoked `hasQueuedThreads` function (and return 0) in thread 2. NPE is happening in thread 2 when it finishes it's job and trying to unlock.

If my assumption is correct you should put *double barrier* in `unlock` method.

```
public void unlock(Path path) {
    ReentrantLock reentrantLock = pathLockMap.get(path);
    if (!reentrantLock.hasQueuedThreads()) { // NPE OCCURS HERE
        pathLockMap.remove(path);
        if (reentrantLock.hasQueuedThreads()) { 
            pathLockMap.put(path, reentrantLock);
        }
    }
    reentrantLock.unlock();
}
```

Comment: This makes sense @mst, not least because I am fundamentally checking-then-acting. To be honest, I'm pretty unhappy about this code in general -- this seems like far too common a scenario for me to be rolling my own (flawed) solution like this, but I also can't find a clear alternative. Is there one that you know of?

Comment: Honestly it was only assumption. I do not believe it's the problem. especially if you're saying "fairly quickly"... Also I was not able to reproduce your issue even with such code.

Comment: I would recommend try to replace `PathLocker`  from working with `Path` to `String` (actual path string). As was said  above probably it's some issues with path equality determination.

Comment: I find it much easier to believe it's race conditions within my own code than that there's a flaw in the hash code and equals methods of a core nio object whose own javadoc describes it as immutable and thread safe!

Comment: I simplified my logic, throw an exception if I can't acquire the lock, and retry on that logic (using Spring's retry AOP stuff). https://gist.github.com/jwilner/14fdd02d5ff7b9df935d Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to just leave the removal to some time-based evicting cache like the one from Guava.

```
public class PathLocker {
    private static final int PROCESSING_TIME = 60;

    private final LoadingCache<Path, Lock> pathLockMap = CacheBuilder.newBuilder()
        .maximumSize(Long.MAX_VALUE)
        .expireAfterAccess(PROCESSING_TIME, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .build(new CacheLoader<Path, Lock>() {
            public Lock load(Path path) {
                return new ReentrantLock();
            }
    });

    public void lock(Path path) {
        Lock lock = pathLockMap.get(path);
        lock.lock();
    }

    public void unlock(Path path) {
        /* Retrieval of the lock again will avoid expiration/eviction in the cache, as counting towards PROCESSING_TIME will be restarted as the other thread is unblocked for processing. */
        Lock lock = pathLockMap.get(path);
        lock.unlock();
    }
}
```

PROCESSING_TIME is some estimated duration to process a single task. The goal is to avoid eviction while the task is currently being processed. During unlocking, an access to the cache will be made, which will restart the eviction timer for similar tasks.

Assuming a PROCESSING_TIME of 10:

1. Thread 1 retrieves the lock at time 0 and starts processing.
2. Thread 2 retrieves the same lock at time 1, but has to wait.
3. Thread 1 unlocks at time 10. Cache will not perform eviction as an access has been made. This allows Thread 2 to safely process later even if its early/last cache access is at time 1.
4. Thread 2 starts processing at time 10.
5. Thread 2 unlocks at time 20.
6. Cache evicts the lock at time 30.